# What is the meaning of Potential Difference in presence of Non-Conservative Induced Electric Field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electric-fields, potential, electromagnetic-induction

**Case 1**

[image]

This is a very commonly discussed case in Electromagnetic Induction. In the case above, we need to find out the potential difference across the rod CD, in the presence of time-varying uniformly distributed cylindrical magnetic field as shown in the figure above.

Here we say that in equilibrium, the non-conservative electric field inside the rod completely balances the conservative electric field developed in rod, due to charge separation and the potential difference which we define in the ends of the rod, is due to the conservative electric field and not due to the non-conservative one, as there is no meaning of potential difference for non-conservative fields. I totally understand and agree with this explanation.

I do not have a doubt in the above case. The problem comes in the case below when we apply similar logic.

**Case 2**

[image]

Consider case 2 above. Here we have a similar time-varying, uniformly distributed cylindrical magnetic field in the region as shown. An equilateral triangular conductor is placed in the magnetic field, with its centroid coinciding with the centre of the cylindrical region. The three branches of the triangle have the SAME resistances. In this case, we wish to find out the potential difference between the points A and B. This is a very common question given in the text-books.

My question is on this case 2.

In this case, we are asked the potential difference between points A and B.

We know that potential difference is a concept associated with a conservative electric field and not with the non-conservative one. Now in this case, how the conservative electric field will come into existence? The free charges inside the conductor will simply start moving just by the effect of the non-conservative induced electric field and there is no need for us to introduce a conservative electric field in this case like an isolated rod in case 1. And, if there is no conservative electric field then there is no concept of the potential difference!

By this logic, either the question itself is wrong, that it is asking for the potential difference between points A and B, in spite of having no existence of the conservative electric field,

OR I am missing something.

Kindly help me.

How do we understand the idea of potential difference in Case 2?

EDIT1: In the triangular conductor, I have changed the resistances of all the sides to be the same.

Comment: *"OR I am missing something."* - that the current through each branch is identical?

Comment: if a current flows in the circuit there is a conservative electric field.The non conservative field merely produces the emf for this

Comment: @Alfred - Yes. The current through each branch is identical, as they are in series.

Comment: @Schwarz : why can't the current flow solely due to the force on charge carriers by non conservative electric field? what is the need for us to introduce conservative electric field in the case 2, for the current to flow?

Comment: Well J=(sigma)E and the E here is conservative.Besides, the line integral of E_non conservative .dl is 0 along two of the sides of the triangle you have shown.

Comment: Devansh, how could the (non-conservative) induced electric field *alone* make the current through the branches equal when the branches have different resistances?

Comment: @Alfred :

I understand the idea when the resistances are different then there will be accumulated charges on their interfaces and that would bring in a conservative electric field and that would change the potential differences across different resistances. 

MY doubt is different. Suppose all the resistances are same then there should not be any existence of conservative electric field and the idea of potential difference then loose the meaning, but it doesn't. How?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz: I do not understand what is the need for any conservative electric field to come.

Comment: EDIT1: In the triangular conductor, I have changed the resistances of all the sides to be the same.

Comment: There would be conservative electric field set up within the loop provided there is current flowing through it.It is the potential difference of this field which they want you to calculate.

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz: Thanks for your kind response. I have a great feeling that you have the answer to my questions. Kindly help me further. 

1. I do not understand how the conservative electric field will come into existence in the case when there is a conductor of uniform resistance. 

2. Your response gives me an impression that current cannot come due to non-conservative electric field. Is it that you are trying to say? What is the reason behind it? 

Kindly help me.

Comment: The emf here is developed becoz of the non conservative electric field acting at the base of the triangle.The other two sides of the triangle are tangential to the field lines and hence the line integral of E.dl in those two sides is 0

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz: That is not correct. All the three sides in case 2 are similarly placed corresponding to the centre of cylindrical magnetic field so the EMF induced in them will be the same.

Comment: They are not similary placed.The lines are tangential to two of the sides.All the emf will be produced on only side AB

Comment: Oh wait.I might have been misinterpreting your figure as I though one of the vertices was at the centre of this magnetic region

Comment: The non-conservative field merely separates the charges at any rate and causes a difference in potential.The current still flows because of the conservative field.It is this potential differnece whcih books want you to find out (scalar potential isn't defined for a non conservative field).Your question is analagous to asking "why doesn't the field of a Daniel cell connected to a resistance push the electrons in normal current electricity without funky changing B fields and why is there a need for a conservative field to be set up there"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109064/discussion-between-devansh-mittal-and-schwarz-kugelblitz).

Comment: @DevanshMittal Also have the look at the answers of this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83237/measuring-voltage-drop-from-induced-current?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @DevanshMittal did you ever figure out what schwarz was trying to say? I still don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And, if there is no conservative electric field then there is no
> concept of the potential difference!

But there *is* a conservative field.

To see this, imagine that the triangle is formed by three resistors (with the same resistance $R$ as per your EDIT 1) and assume the *leads* of the resistors are formed from ideal wire.

Something like this:

[image]

[Image credit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83366/9887)

There is, due to the changing magnetic flux threading the surface bounded by the resistors, a non-conservative electric field such that the line integral of this field (along the closed path defined by the resistors) is non-zero.

But the electric field within the ideal wire leads *must be zero* (even when there is a non-zero current through). *So*, it must be the case that their exists a charge distribution along the wire leads such that that the associated conservative electric field precisely cancels the induced electric field within the wire.

That is, just as in your case 1, the induced electric field *separates* charge against the resulting conservative electric field. If you think about this a bit, you'll see that this charge distribution along the leads is such that one end of the resistor body is more positive than the other end. Thus, there is a potential difference across the resistor (than can be measured if you're careful with the voltmeter lead placement).

Now can you generalize this to the case that the leads have non-zero resistance?

Comment: What if the resistance is uniform throughout the whole triangular loop?

Comment: @FakeMod, Note that I've asked OP if he can generalize to this.

Comment: According to my understanding, the conservative electric field should disappear. I don't want you to just directly give it to the OP,  but I think either confirming or refuting my understanding should not be much of a spoiler for the OP.

Comment: How do you know that the net electric field inside the ideal wires must be zero?

Comment: Please also see my discussion with @Schwatz above and I request you to kindly respond to it.

Comment: I understand the idea that in electro-static condition, the electric field inside the ideal metal wires should be zero, but we are not discussing an electro-static condition here, so kindly explain me how the electric field still should be zero inside the ideal metal wires?

Comment: @DevanshMittal, it's true that, for an 'ordinary' conductor, the current density is $\mathbf{j}=\sigma\mathbf{E}$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity and $\mathbf{E}$ is the net electric field inside the conductor. Consider that case that $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$ (which *defines* the *ideal* conductor) case. For *any* finite current density, the electric field inside the conductor is zero. For example, see [this slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN2UB.png)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: Yes. Thanks for your response. I understand your point now. 

In your original response to the question, are you trying to say that there will be a conservative electric field in the circuit due to the accumulation of charges at the ends of various resistances?

Comment: I've deleted a number of mildly inappropriate comments and/or responses to them.

Comment: I finally understand to a good extent what you actually meant in the above response. Thanks a lot for it.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the time changing magnetic field there is induced non-conservative electric field and the line integral of that field along any closed path is not zero in accordance with Faraday's law. But what is interesting to note is that, if the assumption, that current in the circuit is not changing with time is made for such a case the problem reduces to classic ones. Sine current is not changing the drift velocity remains constant, the work done by the non-conservative electric field must appear in other forms (Conservation Of Energy(Not just mechanical)). It goes into heating the resistors. On doing calculations relating the work done in one cycle by the non-conservative electric field and heat dissipated by the resistors, one obtains the same equations as KVL but the I*R term now corresponds to energy dissipated by a unit charge in going through the resistor and not the potential drop. What we are doing is extrapolating the concept and call this term the potential drop but it actually isn't.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).