# Behaviour of conductor moving in a magnetic field after a long time

Tags: electromagnetism

> [image]

In the above figure, we have a rod moving with some speed in $v$ in a magnetic field $B$, it is said that when at equilibrium the rod generates a surface charge density such that the magnetic field must be cancelled off.

However, I do not understand why this must be the equilibrium state, so this leads to my question, How do you prove that  the equilibrium condition for the system is that a charge density is developed on the body of conductor such that the electrostatic force on conductor cancels the magnetic force?

[related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557743/what-is-the-meaning-of-potential-difference-in-presence-of-non-conservative-indu)

Addendum: Ignore fringe effects and Eddie currents

Answer (score 0):

If the magnetic force is not cancelled by the electric force there is no equilibrium, so the charges will move until there is.

Comment: Hmm so is there no current at equilibrium? Secondly, how do you prove that charges will move until such a way is the condition for equilibrium? If we assume it, then the equation derivations are easy but I don't get how to justify the assumption